In SQL, is it possible/safe to implement optimistic locking using a boolean instead of version increments?
I am trying to implement a simple mutex lock in SQL. My tentative solution is the following:
query = 'UPDATE my_table SET lock_field = 1 WHERE lock_field = 0 AND mutex_id = 17'
if (query.execute() == 1){
  // We own the lock, continue processing
  // Finally: 'UPDATE my_table SET lock_field = 0 WHERE mutex_id = 17'
} else {
  // Somebody else owns the lock, backoff and wait or throw exception etc
}

My question is: is this code safe? Does it guarantee that only a single 'client' can own the lock?
Edited in response to comments to clarify use as a mutex rather than normal DB processing

This is a terrible idea! Use the Database's transactions, as they were intended to be used.

This will only cause you lots of trouble.

"seems much simpler than transactions" how is this simpler? Cleanup would be impossible to guarantee, and it's far less efficient as it requires a committed write to disk, rather than an in-memory lock.

All fair points if a little terse. But seriously -2 downvotes so far for a question that many other people will probably ask/discover separately? How will others learn that this is dangerous if the question is hidden?

Such an approach is safe as it guarantees that no two clients can acquire the "lock" at the the same time. The problem is that this is not sufficient in practice, because this can't guarantee that at least one client will ever be able to acquire the lock; the database will stop doing useful work at some point. Notice that the database doing no work at all upholds the guarantee mentioned above.
The reason is that there is no way to guarantee that the lock will ever get unlocked. Consider the sequence of events
1. `SET lock_field = 1`
2. `query.execute() == 1` is true
3. OutOfMemoryException
4. Thread raised exception within exception, process aborted, destructor did not run
5. The row is now locked forever

There is no way to tell if a client that locked the row has gone away, aborted, had its network connection reset, is caught in an infinite loop, or simply didn't unlock due to a bug. Strictly speaking, the guarantee you mentioned is upheld, but no useful work can be performed.
The only way out of this would be to guess that the client is gone. Hopefully, the client is actually gone. But then we can't be sure if the data protected by the lock is in a consistent state.
Long story short: No, such schemes do not work in practice. Don't try to make them work; they don't. The database itself is fully equipped to guarantee transaction isolation while simultaneously providing a guarantee of forward progress.

You are correct in that a dead client would permanently lock that record. We have semi-manual processes to handle such occurrences. Our main concern is that (at most) only one client will access a record at the same time. In addition, we would need to clean up elsewhere if a client failed, so having the record permanently locked in the event of failure could be seen as a safety feature

If your db can guarantee that the SET lock_field = 1 WHERE lock_field = 0 is executed atomically. Note that details of the query matter.

Yes! That is exactly the point of my question (atomicity of the update query). I can't find any statement elsewhere that this is true for that very simple query given above. The first line in your answer actually answers the question adequately, and I accept your warnings about deadlocking

Note that this is only true if the .execute()-call commits the UPDATE. See here for how and why two clients could both see lock_field = 0 and both successfully UPDATE the same row. Depending on your database-driver, the execute()-call might auto-commit, but you should check.
